# Had been to usage in grammar

Tags: grammar

Read the given sentence:

> He had been to China.

Now, read the following

> He has been to China.

Can you tell me the difference between the two sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had: past perfect, about a time in the past.
http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect.htm

Has: present perfect, about the present.
http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect.htm#perfect

Imagine that he started going to China every year in 2011. By 2013, he had been to China three times. It is 2018. He has been to China eight times.

Comment: It was wonderful!